# send int16 via std_msg/string msg

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All

I am trying to send out int16 from host pc to arduino target. I firstly converted the int16 to two chars and then packaged them into one std_msg/string and send it to the target. My problem is that when I send data which is < 256 and > 0. the high bit will be zero. In this case, the string length will not be two char anymore which cause the com failed. Do anyone know how to fix this problem? thanks a lot.

I understand that my approach is a little awkward. I can use std_msg/int16 do that job directly. I am doing this is aiming to use the same string to carry multiple commands and data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12479/send-int16-via-std_msg/string-msg/) by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Encode the data as either a hex or decimal character string, then parse it on the other end. That is a lot more effort than just sending `std_msgs/int16`, but seems necessary for multiple commands using the same string message type.

Maybe there is a better way to approach your design problem. Could you instead use multiple message types? Multiple topics?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2011-12-30**:
Agreed; using multiple topics with the appropriate message types is the right way to do this. And you get demultiplexing for free rather than having to do it yourself.